# importing promped xls file into Excel using VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I'm trying to create a Macro that will import .xls  file into other spreadsheet.
Only issue is that this file is stored directly in Dated folder so every time I need to pull it from different one. Is there a way to get box that prompt's you asking for that specific folder. Name of the file is same all the time. Thanks

To Clarify:
Dated folder is: K:.........\2016-01-18(example)\”fileName.xls”
So I need box that will prompt the date in format “yyyy-mm-dd” to call up the correct folder from above destination and then function to pull specific (constant) "fileName.xls"

Comment: Could you put the code of the macro you created? As the format of the folder's address, please?

Comment: or perhaps you could avoid the prompt and just the current date as a start if it's always the current day or a day behind or something like that... To get a prompt see [Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff836226.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

The following function will do it. fileLoc is the fully qualified path to the folder, fileMain is the filename (note, the code will wildcard this) and extension is hopefully evident (. and then the extension, again wildcards allowed):

```
Public Function getFileName(ByVal fileLoc As String, ByVal fileMain As String, ByVal extension As String) As String
    Dim fDialog As Object
    Set fDialog = Application.FileDialog(3) ‘File picker dialog box.
    Dim varFile As Variant
    fDialog.AllowMultiSelect = False
    fDialog.Title = "Select file for input: "
    fDialog.InitialFileName = fileLoc + "*" + fileMain + "*" + extension
    If fDialog.Show = True Then
        For Each varFile In fDialog.SelectedItems
            getFileName = varFile
        Next
    End If
End Function
```

You can use this to navigate folders as well.